# Sybase regexp, substr, instr function to split the string

Tags: sql, sybase, substr, regexp-substr, sybase-ase15

I have the below data in a table.

| row_num | desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First Name/Last Name - Middle Name |
| 2 | FirstName/LastName - MiddleName |
| 3 | FirstName/LastName |

I am looking for the desired output as below

| row_num | desc_1 | desc_2 | desc_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First Name | Last Name | Middle Name |
| 2 | FirstName | LastName | MiddleName |
| 3 | FirstName | LastName | NULL |

In sybase I am not able to use functions like `SUBSTR(desc,INSTR(desc,' ',1,1) + 1)` . Need some inputs on how to achieve the desired result set in Sybase

Comment: Are there consistent delimiters between first, last and middle? What happens if a first or last name is hyphenated?

Comment: I haven't see any examples with hyphenated data. So, far this is the pattern I have seen. And in some case Middle Name is NULL, in such case I have to populate it as NULL

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: please update the question to include an example where the middle name is NULL

Comment: updated the question and we use ASE Sybase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- this is `Sybase ASE` so the functions of interest will be `substring()` and `charindex()`
- OP wants a set-based SQL solution (eg, we're *not* parsing `@variables` as part of a looping/cursor-based construct)
- all `desc` columns are of the format `firstname/lastname - middlename` (so we can search for the static delimiters `/` and `-`)

The general approach is to use `charindex()` to find the positions of our delimiters and then feed these positions to `substring()`.

Since `ASE` does not support CTEs we'll use a derived table to generate the delimiter start positions:

```
select  src.row_num,
        substring([desc], 1, dt.pos1-1)                 as desc_1,
        substring([desc], dt.pos1+1,
                          case when dt.pos2=0
                               then 100 
                               else dt.pos2-dt.pos1-1
                          end)                          as desc_2,
        case when dt.pos2=0 
             then NULL 
             else substring([desc], dt.pos2+3, 100) 
        end                                             as desc_3
from    src
join    (select row_num,
                charindex("/",  [desc]) as pos1,
                charindex(" - ",[desc]) as pos2
        from    src) dt
on      src.row_num = dt.row_num
order by 1
go
```

**NOTES:**

- `desc` is a reserved word in `ASE` hence the need to bracket the name (`[desc]`)
- for the 2nd `substring()` replace `100` with a number that's at least as long as the `desc` column
- we could eliminate the derived table (`dt`) by replacing each `dt.posX` with the associated `charindex()` call (obviously the `substring()` calls would become a bit unwieldly)

This generates:

```
 row_num desc_1     desc_2      desc_3
 ------- ---------- ----------- ---------
       1 First Name Middle Name Last Name
       2 FirstName  MiddleName  LastName
```

---

FWIW, SQL Function/Reference manuals for the various Sybase RDBMS products:

- [ASE functions](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/2df920cd5b1644e5a065d55b637d5e92/aac5d4b5bc2b1014bdfec9c98122b55f.html)
- [SQLAnywhere functions](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/81fc4e506ce21014b8e8f1dced6efa7e.html)
- [IQ functions](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_IQ/a898e08b84f21015969fa437e89860c8/a5266adc84f210159f7ce9b53c36e5d7.html)
- Advantage - having problems at the moment locating online documentation

Comment: I am getting the below error for desc_3 column when the value is NULL. How can I overcome this error
```Invalid length parameter with value of -17 passed to the substring function.```

Comment: @Bruce easy solution is to throw in some `case` statements; answer updated to eliminate the `substring()`/negative-value error

Comment: Thank you. I am also trying below approach to remove ``` / ``` and ``` - ``` from the original value and tried using ```str_replace(desc,'/','') ```.  This will replace only ```/```, but I wanted to replace both ```/ , - ```. How can I achieve this ?